# convert datetime minutes and year in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-datareader

I have a dataframe as below

```
customerid            mydate

    123              2016-08-15 18:22:40
    234              2017-08-15 42:34.04
    234              39:35.01
```

the mydate column is mixed, some have years with time others only time. The mydate column is an object but I want to convert it into date time as below

```
df['mydate']     =  pd.to_datetime(df['mydate'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

but i get the below error

```
ValueError: time data 39:35.01 doesn't match format specified
```

Comment: are you sure your data is correct?  As far as I know there are only 24 hrs in a day. Even if it is in right format which date you want to assign where there's no date?

Comment: Why there's dot instead of colon in some time objects? Besides, what's `42`? that doesn't seem like a valid time. At least on earth. Which planet/galaxy are you from?:))

Comment: As you have pointed out since some entries do not have year, month and date, they will not follow the format you expect. Furthermore your data in the date column is not homogeneous, just from your example of 3 entries im seeing 3 different formats. Standardize all your dates first, then try to use a single format to match them all.

Comment: What is expected output from your data sample?

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
#get today date
today = pd.Timestamp.today().floor('D')
#split dates by whitespace
s = df['mydate'].str.split()
#first part convert to datetime if possible replace non exist dates to today
df['date'] =  pd.to_datetime(s.str[0], errors='coerce').fillna(today)
#non exist second part of splited values replace by first part
s1 = s.str[1].combine_first(s.str[0])
#if 3. character from back is . add zero hours and convert to timedeltas
df['td']  =  pd.to_timedelta(s1.mask(s1.str[-3] == '.', '00:'+ s1))
#add timedelta to dates
df['datefinal'] = df['date'] + df['td']
print (df)
  customerid               mydate       date              td  \
0        123  2016-08-15 18:22:40 2016-08-15        18:22:40   
1        234  2017-08-15 42:34.04 2017-08-15 00:42:34.040000   
2        234             39:35.01 2018-11-21 00:39:35.010000   

                datefinal  
0 2016-08-15 18:22:40.000  
1 2017-08-15 00:42:34.040  
2 2018-11-21 00:39:35.010
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `mydate` column has non-datetime values so you need to cross-check data source integrity. And even if format was right, with the information provided, such a conversion isn't feasible, neither in Python nor in any other language (how would you know for which date, that particular time was recorded?).